# Apache Stanbol: /ontonet giving me 404 error

Tags: ontology, apache-stanbol

In my stanbol instance, its showing only following services.

**/enhancer

/topic

/entityhub

/sparql**

/ontonet giving me 404 error.
I am using the org.apache.stanbol.launchers.full-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Any configuration to enable **/ontonet** and others.